# R - fit a smooth curve through my data points

Tags: r, plot, curve-fitting

I wrote following script in `R`:

```
F<-c(1.485, 1.052, .891, .738, .623, .465, .343, .184, .118, .078, 1.80, 
            2.12, 2.31, 2.83, 3.14, 3.38, 7.70, 15.35, 20.72, 22.93)
A<-c(4.2, 4.8, 5.0, 5.2, 5.3, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 3.8, 3.5, 3.4, 2.9,
     2.7, 2.5, 1.2, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5)

Amplitude <- A/2          
Flog <- log(F)
plot(Flog, Amplitude, type="p", lwd=1,   
     xlab=expression(paste(frequency,'  ', log[e](Hz/s^-1))),   
     ylab=expression(paste(amplitude,'  ', U/V)),   
     )
```

The curve I want to fit is of the kind `1/(sqrt(1+x^2))`. Is there a way I can achieve a `smooth fit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `nls()` function in R.  It is designed to work on variables in a `data.frame`, so you will need to make a data frame to contain your `F` and `A` variables.

I'm not sure what the purpose of your `Amplitude` and 'Flog`variables are; in this example I assumed you wanted to predict`A`values from`F` values using your equation.

```
#define data
F<-c(1.485, 1.052, .891, .738, .623, .465, .343, .184, .118, .078, 1.80, 
            2.12, 2.31, 2.83, 3.14, 3.38, 7.70, 15.35, 20.72, 22.93)
A<-c(4.2, 4.8, 5.0, 5.2, 5.3, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 3.8, 3.5, 3.4, 2.9,
     2.7, 2.5, 1.2, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5)

#put data in data frame
df = data.frame(F=F, A=A)

#fit model
fit <- nls(A~k1/sqrt(k2 + F^2)+k3, data = df, start = list(k1=6,k2=1,k3=0))
summary(fit)

Formula: A ~ k1/sqrt(k2 + F^2) + k3

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
k1  9.09100    0.17802  51.067  < 2e-16 ***
k2  2.55225    0.08465  30.150 3.36e-16 ***
k3  0.06881    0.03787   1.817   0.0869 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.05793 on 17 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.062e-07

#plot results
require(ggplot2)
quartz(height=3, width=3)
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(y=A, x=F), size=3)  + geom_line(data=data.frame(spline(df$F, predict(fit, df$A))), aes(x,y), color = 'red')
quartz.save('StackOverflow_29062205.png', type='png')
```

That code produces the following graph:

[image]

Comment: You need to have `ggplot2` and all necessary dependencies installed to use the script, but that's just for plotting.  The part that does the fitting is `nls()`.

Comment: Thanks, I reinstalled R, somehow my tcl/tk libraries were deleted and i couldn't `library("ggplot2")`. I could produce the plot now. But what if I need to logarithmize the x-axis (here:F), so instead of F i use `Flog <- log(F)`. What parameters do I have to change. I tried to substitute every F with Flog, but it doesn' work.

Comment: One way would be to just redefine F at the top of the script: `F <- log(F)`.

Comment: If I redefine F, following error occurs: `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

Comment: I'm sorry I can't continue to troubleshoot your problem for you.  What part of my code don't you understand?  What questions about how the code works do you still have?  Do you understand what the `nls` function is doing?

Comment: I understand, I begin to understand `nls` more. I will experiment with it until I find the solution. Thanks for the help.